# Spread Range Dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of 'range dates' with a value. 
For example:

```
Start     End      Value
1/1/2017  10/1/2017  10
5/1/2017  8/1/2017   20
12/1/2017 13/1/2017  40
```

What I wanna have as output is a dataframe (pandas) with a calendar from **1/1/2017** to **31/12/2017** where each value is add all to days in range between start and end.
My current solution is:
1) Create a calendar dataframe
2) Iterate over Dates and for each range date using np.where it is possible to add the 'value' to calendar dataframe.

Do you know if there are other ways to figure out this problem?

This is the result which I wanna have (dataframe with 2 columns):

```
1/1/2017 10 
2/1/2017 10
3/1/2017 10 
4/1/2017 10
5/1/2017 10 + 20
6/1/2017 10 + 20
7/1/2017 10 + 20
8/1/2017 10 + 20 
9/1/2017 10
10/1/2017 10
11/1/2017 0
12/1/2017 40
13/1/2017 10
14/1/2017 0
etc.
```

Comment: Ciao Marcello, could you please provide an excerpt of the result you want to get? Moreover, what do you mean by _list of 'range dates' with a value_? Do you mean a python list? Do you mean a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

If datetimes are not overlaping is possible create `Series` with `DatetimeIndex` and add all missing values of datetimes of years by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

s = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Value,pd.date_range(r.Start, r.End)) for r in df.itertuples()])
s = s.groupby(level=0).sum()
#print (s)

rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
s2 = s.reindex(rng, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (s2.head(15))

2017-01-01    10
2017-01-02    10
2017-01-03    10
2017-01-04    10
2017-01-05    30
2017-01-06    30
2017-01-07    30
2017-01-08    30
2017-01-09    10
2017-01-10    10
2017-01-11     0
2017-01-12    40
2017-01-13    40
2017-01-14     0
2017-01-15     0
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Last for DataFrame use `rename_axis` with `reset_index`:

```
df = s2.rename_axis('dates').reset_index(name='values')
print (df.head(15))
        dates  values
0  2017-01-01      10
1  2017-01-02      10
2  2017-01-03      10
3  2017-01-04      10
4  2017-01-05      30
5  2017-01-06      30
6  2017-01-07      30
7  2017-01-08      30
8  2017-01-09      10
9  2017-01-10      10
10 2017-01-11       0
11 2017-01-12      40
12 2017-01-13      40
13 2017-01-14       0
14 2017-01-15       0
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is possible to have overlapping dates

Comment: @Marcello - Ok, so what happens if overlapping? do you need aggregate - it means if same values for same datetimes in `s` need mean of `value`s ?

Comment: I've just updated with a sample. With overlapping I have to sum (or other simple operations) . It is possible to have overlapping and for each couple of dates we can have any values

Comment: @Marcello - Edited answer, there is aggregate `sum` by `level=0`, it menas by `DatetimeIndex`

Comment: It works (and it is faster than my solution) Thanks a lot